# Using mocks with angular's scenario runner

Tags: javascript, mocking, tdd, angularjs

In angular unit tests, it's possible to create mocks and inject them into controllers. I would like to do the same in e2e tests. Is this possible? I'm looking around but can't find much.

I think the answer may have something to do with [ngMockE2E.$httpBackend](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E.$httpBackend).

Here is an example of what I would hope it would look like:

```
describe('server status', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
        var backend = new HttpBackend(); // or however you get an instance
        backend.get('/foo', 'bar');
        injectBackend(backend);
    });

    it('should display data from server', function() {
        expect(element('.dataFromServer').text()).toBe('bar');
    });
});
```

Is this possible?

(I am using Testacular and Jasmine, for what it's worth.)

Comment: all i could find is this, a google groups topic on the matter ->  [(here's a link)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/AY_eom9X_zA/lVaQAXdmg9UJ) im not too sure if this is the correct thing but just trying to be helpful ^.^(considering you have little in terms of answers :/)

Comment: The [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend) you referenced are pretty clear about how to setup the $httpBackend for mocking. The odd thing about the setup is that you setup expectations on the $httpBackend instance (from $injector) instead of the $http directly in your service. My experience has been to ditch the angular test framework and stub out what you need since JS makes it so simple.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use [jasmine's spies](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Spies), which is used for spies, stubs, and mocks.  Here's [an example of creating an instance of a controller with two stubbed dependencies](https://github.com/roytruelove/angular-grunt-coffeescript/blob/master/src/test/detailsView/detailsViewSpec.coffee).  It's in coffeescript but you can convert it [here](http://js2coffee.org/).

Depending on what you're looking for though $httpBackend sounds like what I would do.  (see SonOfNun's comment)